# How does a template string exclude certain fields?

Tags: typescript

I want to write constraints for the method field

```
  type event = {
   [k: `on${string}`]:(e:string)=>void
  }
```

But I want the event argument to be number for fields that don't start with 'on'

```
  type event = {
   [k: `${xxx}`]:(e:number)=>void //  XXX does not start with 'on'
  }
```

How w do I write this XXX?

Comment: Do you have a predefined list for XXX and all the others should start with "on"?

Comment: I do have a list starting with on, but XXX is reserved for customization

Comment: There are no negated types in TypeScript, so there's no specific type that matches "all strings except those that start with `'on'`".  See [ms/TS#17867](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867) for the relevant feature request.  You can't do it with a specific type, but you can represent it as a recursive generic type like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NrG2Vm), where the compiler *checks* that a candidate type meets those constraints.  Do you want that written up as an answer or is there some unmet use case?

Comment: Try `Record`, if that helps you achieve what you want.

Comment: thanks  jcalz !  
 I  learned that my idea might not work!

Nalin Ranjan your Record Can't open!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following... See if that helps... However, the trick applied is to split the keys to be coming from two different types and then combining them using the support of [Mapped Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) from Typescript.

```
type GuessItsACallback = (x: number) => void;

type WithoutOnKeys = {
    key1: GuessItsACallback
    key2: GuessItsACallback
}

type WithOnKeys = {
    onKey1: GuessItsACallback,
    onKey2: GuessItsACallback
}

type CombinedKeys = WithoutOnKeys & WithOnKeys;

const combinedValue: CombinedKeys = {
    key1: (x: number) => console.log(x + 10),
    key2: (y: number) => console.log(y + 20),
    onKey1: (x: number) => console.log(x + 10),
    onKey2: (x: number) => console.log(x + 10)
}

const withoutOnValues: WithoutOnKeys = combinedValue;
const withOnValues: WithOnKeys = combinedValue;

withoutOnValues.key1(30);

withOnValues.onKey1(50);

type DesiredEvents = {
    [Property in keyof CombinedKeys]: GuessItsACallback
}

const eventsContainer: DesiredEvents = combinedValue;
const eventsContainerWithoutOnKeys: WithOnKeys = eventsContainer;
const eventsContainerWithOnKeys: WithoutOnKeys = eventsContainer;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
My intention is for key1 and onKey1 to be function types with different arguments

Comment: Can you please try giving onKey1 a different function type .. and I have a strong feeling that this should still work...